# Insert PNG comment block (iTXt) using javascript

Tags: javascript, png, metadata

I want to insert a UTF-8 comment in a PNG. Context is in a modern browser : export -canvas- and add some metadata into PNG before user download, later import it and read metadata.

[PNG specs for metadata, says about iTXt](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11iTXt)

I see a [good answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243115/how-do-i-insert-a-png-comment-block-when-saving-an-html5-canvas-using-javascript#answer-48272162) about this, with all steps to achieve a tEXt chunk but without code.

I found a simple nodejs library [node-png-metadata](https://github.com/kujirahand/node-png-metadata) to manage PNG metadata.

With this resources, I succeeded some tricks like insert a chunk and read it, but it seem's it's not a valid iTXt chunk (same with tEXt chunk), because tools like pngchunks or pnginfo can't understand it.

See this [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv5y9m2u/182/) for playing import a PNG it will add metadata and display it ! Test with tEXt or iTXt chunk

Near line 21 some tests around creation of the chunk

```js
var txt = {
  sample: '@à$'
};

var newchunk = metadata.createChunk("tEXt", "Comment"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"heremycommentl"); // works but not conform
var newchunk = metadata.createChunk("TEXt", "Comment"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"heremycommentl"); // result invalid png
var newchunk = metadata.createChunk("iTXt", "Source"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"00fr"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"Source"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+""+JSON.stringify(txt));// works but not conform
```

Beside Resulting PNG is corrupted if chunk type name first char is upper case ? TEXt

If some of you have understanding to share, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

Chunk names are case-sensitive, `tEXt` is the name of the chunk, `TEXt` is not. And since the first letter is uppercase, making the chunk critical, no PNG tools can understand the image since there is now an unknown critical chunk.

The `iTXt` one is broken because the compression flag and method are stored directly, not as the ASCII representation of the numbers. Changing it to:

```js
metadata.createChunk("iTXt", "Source"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"fr"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"Source"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+""+JSON.stringify(txt));
```

makes it work.

`metadata.createChunk("tEXt", "Comment"+String.fromCharCode(0x00)+"heremycommentl")` doesn't cause any issues with `pnginfo`, perhaps you confused the error there with the `iTXt` one?