# Inserting ICC profile obtained from a jpg image into a png image in frontend Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, png, exif

I am trying to insert ICC profile data parsed from a JPG/JPEG image back into a PNG image. I have parsed this data taking help from [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1207) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152279/reading-icc-profile-from-image-with-javascript) source, But I am unable to find solutions for re-inserting this profile back into a PNG Image. I have looked at [PNG specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#5DataRep) and tried to insert the data byte wise (following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48272162/5835403) instructions) but the newly formed image is getting corrupted. Any help or guidance towards the right direction is highly appreciated.

I am trying to achieve the above task in frontend and I am using React-JS for the same.

Comment: "_tried to insert the data byte wise_" - add that code to your question. Add what you actually did and how we can reproduce that the resulting PNG is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

try this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rgba-image/png), with the following package you can convert imageData into .png